# VBA Select Case type incompatibility

Tags: vba, types, runtime, incompatibility

I have got this sub and this function you see below. It gives me a runtime error 13: type incompatibility on the following row and I dont know whats wrong

`Select Case ((Cell.Offset(0, -2).Value - Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value) - (CellX.Offset(0, -2).Value - CellX.Offset(0, -1).Value))`

I am working on this piece of code for hours, so you are my last resort.

You may also need to know, that in the Cells of `Range rngX` there are cells with floating point numbers and cells with no content and in `Cell.Offset(0,-2)` and `Cell.Offset(0,-1)` there are integral numbers or cells with no content

```
Sub X()

    Dim boolFunction as Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IntTab")
        boolFunction = Function1(.Range("O2:O19"))
        boolFunction = Function1(.Range("AA2:AA19"))
    End With

End Sub


Function Function1(ByVal rngX As Range) As Boolean

    Dim intTab As Integer

    For Each Cell In rngX
        intTab = 1
        For Each CellX In rngX
            Select Case Cell.Value - CellX.Value
                Case Is > 0
                    'Do nothing
                Case Is = 0
                    Select Case ((Cell.Offset(0, -2).Value - Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value) - (CellX.Offset(0, -2).Value - CellX.Offset(0, -1).Value))
                        Case Is > 0
                            'Do nothing
                        Case Is = 0
                            'Do nothing
                        Case Is < 0
                            intTab = intTab + 1
                    End Select
                Case Is < 0
                    intTab = intTab + 1
            End Select
        Next CellX
        Cell.Offset(0, (-9)).Value = intTab
    Next Cell

    Function1 = True

End Function
```

Comment: `Option Explicit`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that those *"cells with no content"* may have some spaces content

so just convert them to zero via the `Val()` function

```
Select Case ((val(cell.Offset(0, -2).Value) - val(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value)) - (val(cellX.Offset(0, -2).Value) - val(cellX.Offset(0, -1).Value)))
```